# Starting and killing a process based on time

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have a bunch of different processes (mostly shell scripts) that need to start at a specific time, and then need to be killed some hours later. Right now I start them via cron and then use another cron job to get the process ID and kill them. Not the cleanest way, especially if there are multiple copies of the same script running.

I was wondering if there was some kind of a wrapper available that would start a process (in a subshell? or fork?) and then kill it at a given time. Googling didn't yield much, so I wanted to check with the all-knowing stackoverflow community before diving in to write my own.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you already have is the correct solution. Starting via cron, ending via cron. On the issue of multiple instances of same script, is this your need. Your requirements demand more than one instance of the same script be running?

**get the process ID and kill them**. when you say that you mean the scripts log their pids in a file which you use to stop them? Or you use **ps/pidof**?

Answer (score 0):

[Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) is an excellent tool to use as a wrapper to control/monitor processes.

Your situation would fall under the service test feature, where you'd take an action based on [process uptime](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#uptime_testing).

```
 check process myapp with pidfile /var/run/myapp.pid
    start program = "/etc/init.d/myapp start"
    stop program = "/etc/init.d/myapp stop"
    if uptime == 3 hours then stop
```